# Can the subject of “se mettre à faire qqch” be an inanimate object?

Tags: constructions

“Se mettre à faire qqch” means [to start doing sth](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/se-mettre-%C3%A0-faire). Can Can the subject of “se mettre à faire qqch” be an inanimate object? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes I remember something I heard from a movie (horror) : `" Et là la poupée commença a se mettre à faire des mouvements "` .

Comment: @RosaAmbre "Commencer à faire quelque chose" et "Se mettre à faire quelque chose" sont des constructions synonymes dans la plupart des cas. "Commencer à se mettre à faire quelque chose" est donc redondant.

Comment: [_On voit mal le Tour se mettre à faire la quête les dimanches au Ventoux pour le salut des dopés._ Libération (2002)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/se-mettre-%C3%A0-faire).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for instance:

> J'ai allumé mon téléphone et il s'est mis à faire n'importe quoi.

Not an inanimate object but you could also have:

> Lorsque je suis sorti, il s'est mis à pleuvoir.

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

> J'ai branché l'aspirateur et il s'est mis à faire un bruit bizarre.